# Angular2: Testing component with dependency injection

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I have a simple yet complicated (for now) component : It is just a login form 
so I will not paste the html . Looks like this :

```
login.component.ts

@Component({
    selector: 'login',
    providers: [ModuleLoaderService, LoginService],
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    directives: [CORE_DIRECTIVES, RouterLink],
    pipes: [TranslationPipe]
})

export class LoginComponent {

//... some stuff
    constructor(public router: Router, public http: Http, private _translation: TranslationService,
                private _loginService: LoginService, private _moduleLoaderService: ModuleLoaderService) {
                    // do stuff using translation, etc
                }

                ....
 ngOnInit() {
`....bla bla
}
```

Here is the test I start trying which I think is totally out:

```
describe('Login form', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
                                provide(Http, {useFactory: (backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
                                    return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
                                }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]}),
                                TranslationService,
                                LoginService
    ]);

    it('should check translated labels', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
        return tcb.createAsync(MockLoginComponent).then((fixture) => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
            expect(true).toBe(true);
        });
    }));
});
```

and my TranslationService:

```
import { Injectable } from 'angular2/core';
import { TranslateService } from 'ng2-translate';

@Injectable()
export class TranslationService {

    constructor( private _translate: TranslateService ) {
        //
     }
```

Errors :

Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found): http://localhost:9876/ng2-translate

I want to start writing tests for this component . The first test I thought would be a good start : testing the translated labels  are correct (or anything else simple enough). I have no idea how to inject or mock them up all these constructor arguments . Any hint truly appreciated.

Update:
So I kinda ignored component dependency for now and I was able to actually get the component for testing :

```
describe('Login form', () => {
    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(XHRBackend, { useClass: MockBackend }),
        provide(Router, { useClass: MockRouter }),
        TranslateService,
        TranslationService,
        LoginService,
        provide(TranslateLoader, {
            useFactory: (http: Http) => new TranslateStaticLoader(http, 'assets/i18n', '.json'),
            deps: [Http]
        }),
        TranslateService,
        ModuleLoaderService
    ]);

    it('should pre-populate username and pass from localStorage', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
        return tcb.createAsync(LoginComponent).then((fixture) => {
            fixture.detectChanges();
            let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
            localStorage.setItem('username', 'storedUsername');           
            expect(compiled.querySelector('input .ng-untouched')).toHaveText('storedUsername');
        });
    }));
```

The css selector doesn't seem to work and the translated labels do not show in Karma browser either ...

Comment: What about providing a more concrete example about what you want to test. What have you tried? Where is the problem?

Comment: Thank you for looking. So I added my attempt to the description: As I mentioned before I need to get started with testing this component, for now lets say I just need to test if the translated labels for this login form are there and correct. For that, I thought I need to inject the TranslationService (see my translation service which relies on ng2-translate). Obviously it doesn't work because I have no idea how to do that. Thank you !

Comment: I am one step further: I fixed the error of not having some of the needed libraries by adding them to the karma.conf.js. Now I can go deal with the actual test. Next: fix the providers !

Comment: @ng-flo what exactly did you do to fix it, because I see the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This might help. I'm not use TS myself (only Dart) but it runs the tests without errors (doesn't actually test anything).

Some links that might be helpful

- https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed
- https://github.com/ericmdantas/angular2-typescript-todo

**test/some.spec.ts**

```
import {setBaseTestProviders} from 'angular2/testing';
import {
    TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser';
import {Http, ConnectionBackend, BaseRequestOptions} from 'angular2/http';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from 'angular2/router';
import {
    //AsyncTestCompleter,
    TestComponentBuilder,
    beforeEachProviders,
    beforeEach,
    describe,
    // el,
    expect,
    inject,
    injectAsync,
    it,
} from 'angular2/testing';
import {Component, provide, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
import {LoginComponent, TranslationService} from '../src/app';
import {MockBackend} from "angular2/src/http/backends/mock_backend";

setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

describe('Login form', () => {
  beforeEachProviders(() => [provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useClass: LoginComponent}), TestComponentBuilder, ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
    provide(Http, {
      useFactory: (backend:ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions:BaseRequestOptions) => {
        return new Http(backend, defaultOptions);
      }, deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
    }),
    TranslationService,
  ]);

  it('should check translated labels', injectAsync([TestComponentBuilder], (tcb) => {
    return tcb.createAsync(LoginComponent).then((fixture) => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
      console.debug(compiled);
      expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
  }));
});
```

**test.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>angular2 playground</title>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jasmine/2.4.1/boot.js"></script>


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.15/testing.dev.js"></script>
    <script>

        Promise.all([
          System.import('test/some.spec.ts')
        ])
        .then(window.onload)
                .catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**src/app.ts**

```
import {EventEmitter, HostListener, Component, Directive, Output} from 'angular2/core';
import {Http} from 'angular2/http';
import {RouterLink, Router, RouteConfig, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';


export class TranslationService {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'home-cmp',
  template: '<div>home</div>'
})
class HomeComponent {
}

@Component({
  selector: 'login',
  providers: [TranslationService],
  template: '<div>login</div>',
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private _translation:TranslationService) {
    // do stuff using translation, etc
  }
}

@Component({
  directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet],
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<a [routerLink]="['/Home']">Home</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/Login']">Login</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>`,
})
@RouteConfig([
  {path: '/home', component: HomeComponent, name: 'Home', useAsDefault: true},
  {path: '/login', component: LoginComponent, name: 'Login'},
])
export class App {
}
```

Comment: I tried that and I get this error : debug.html:38 Failed: No provider for ApplicationRef! (LoginComponent -> Router -> RouteRegistry -> Token RouterPrimaryComponent -> ApplicationRef)
Error: DI Exception

Comment: Sorry, can't reproduce.